# Form inputs getting saved in MySQL database as '1'

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, localhost

I have the below code in PHP to test saving data from a simple web form into MySQL. The form has two basic boxes which accept text: input1 and input2. When I complete these and hit submit, there are no issues. However, when I access the database in MySQL I just see '1' where I should see the actual text I entered. At first I thought this acted like a boolean but both fields are set up to accept VARCHAR (and set up as null). The 1 appears whether I enter text in the form or not.

The very basic HTML form:

```
<form action="signupform.php" method="post" />
<p> Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" /></p>
<p> Input 2: <input type="text" name="input2" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here's the PHP used:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

if (!$connection) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$connection_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'demo');

if (!$connection_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . 'DB_NAME' . ': ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

$value1 = isset($_POST['input1']);
$value2 = isset($_POST['input2']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO form1 (input1, input2) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2')";
if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST); exit;` at the top of your PHP file and see what it says.

Comment: you can eliminate all of this sort of pain from basic stuff by using a PHP framework, which will boilerplate stuff like this and leave you to do the fun stuff

Comment: Just remove the isset() to see if it works.

Comment: side note: **prepare** your string before querying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing something wrong here

```
$value1 = isset($_POST['input1']);
$value2 = isset($_POST['input2']);
```

what do you do here is, you're saving the boolean value. to the variables `$value1` & `$value2` respectively. That is `True = 1` & `False = 0` and You're inserting it to the database. No wonder you have 0 and 1 in the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['input1']) && isset($_POST['input2'])){
   $value1 = $_POST['input1'];
   $value2 = $_POST['input2'];
}
```

this would do

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense now... Thanks a lot!